# Problem converting CSV to XLS, using unoconv

Tags: linux, unoconv

I have a file that I need to convert to XLS and upload to the site. But this site is very format sensitive. If I convert the file on my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS), everything is fine. If on the server (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) an error occurs. The program version and all of its components are identical on the two machines.

```
root@server:~$ unoconv --version
unoconv 0.7
Written by Dag Wieers <dag@wieers.com>
Homepage at http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/

platform posix/linux
python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
LibreOffice 6.4.7.2
```

The most interesting thing is that the converted file on my main machine is 600 bytes larger. I tried to find the cause of the problem on the Internet, but as I understand, I am the first one to encounter this problem.

```
root@server:~$ ls -l
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28160 Dec  7 22:54 file_computer.xls
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 27648 Dec  7 22:54 file_server.xls
```